# Null Exception On Getting Unread message from a particular number

Tags: android, smsmanager

I want to get unread message from a particular number by the following code .

```
public void getUnreadMessage() {
        Cursor smsInboxCursor1 = getContentResolver().query(
                Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), new String[] {},
                "read = 0 and address='" + pre_address + "'", null, null);
        int indexBody = smsInboxCursor1.getColumnIndex("body");
        int indexAddress = smsInboxCursor1.getColumnIndex("address");
        if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor1.moveToFirst())
            return;

        do {

            String str = "SMS From: " + smsInboxCursor1.getString(indexAddress)
                    + "\n" + smsInboxCursor1.getString(indexBody) + " \n";
            fromNumber = smsInboxCursor1.getString(indexAddress);
            smsBody.add(smsInboxCursor1.getString(indexBody));
            // arrayAdapter.add(str);
            status.add(false);

        } while (smsInboxCursor1.moveToNext());
    }
```

But when I try to call this function using the following code , I get null exception .

```
try {
            getUnreadMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unread message is "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

The exception is "null" exception . Where is the problem ? How can I solve this ? 
The full stacktrace is as following :

```
  09-17 12:23:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(6882): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    09-17 12:23:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(6882):     at com.commlink.smscheck.SmsActivity.getUnreadMessage(SmsActivity.java:102)
    09-17 12:23:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(6882):     at com.commlink.smscheck.SmsActivity.onCreate(SmsActivity.java:63)
    09-17 12:23:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(6882):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
    09-17 12:23:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(6882):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
    09-17 12:23:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(6882):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
    09-17 12:23:16.482: E/AndroidRuntime(6882):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you please share the full stacktrace?

Comment: The question is updated .

Comment: check `smsInboxCursor1` is not null and add `smsInboxCursor1.moveToFirst()` before using that

Comment: Thanks shayan for providing nice answer